# How to get the number of rows that would have been returned?

Tags: sql, count, limit, row

In the following query:

```
SELECT column1,column2 FROM table1 ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 0,30
```

How can I find out the number of rows that would have been returned were it not for the `LIMIT`?

**Edit:** I am looking for a way to work this into the query above and not do a separate query. (If possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this query:

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS column1,column2 FROM table1 ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 0,30;
```

You can retrieve the number of rows the previous SELECT found with

```
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

If you really must do it with one query, you'll have to use a sub select (which'll have the disatvantage of adding an extra column to every row..)

```
 SELECT column1,column2,s.total FROM table1,
    (select count(*) as total from table1) s 
 ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 0,30;
```

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: Ah, this looks like what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;
```

Comment: Is this part of my query above, or a separate query? I knew how to do this... I was hoping for a way to work it into my existing query.

Comment: @George Edison: Separate query - standard SQL requires you to define a GROUP BY clause for columns that don't use aggregate functions (COUNT, MIN, MAX, etc) in the SELECT clause, which would affect your resultset.

Comment: What would that look like anyway?

Comment: well, you could do it like: 

    SELECT column1,column2, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) AS rows FROM table1 ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 0,30;

but I think that is less efficient.

Comment: @Johan: True, but it's going to add the same value to every row returned.

Comment: Could you create a view using OP's query and use this on the view? If not, a nested query would be the way to go.